# Inheriting dependencies when running unit tests from command line

Tags: julia

I am trying to run Julia unit tests from the command line but the unit tests fail to run because they cannot find a dependency that I am using in my main project. How can I make this work? The actual command that I try to execute is `julia test/test_blueprint.jl` from the project root. Here follows more details.

#### Details about the setup

My project is located at the path `/home/jonas/prog/julia/blueprint`. In that directory, I have a `Project.toml` file containing these lines:

```
name = "blueprint"
uuid = "c1615a0c-c255-402d-ae34-0b88819b43c6"
authors = [""]
version = "0.1.0"

[deps]
FunctionalCollections = "de31a74c-ac4f-5751-b3fd-e18cd04993ca"
Setfield = "efcf1570-3423-57d1-acb7-fd33fddbac46"
```

along with the `Manifest.toml` file.

I have a subdirectory at `test/` with unit tests that I created following [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-test-your-software-with-julia-4050379a9f3) and that directory contains another `Project.toml` file containing

```
[deps]
Test = "8dfed614-e22c-5e08-85e1-65c5234f0b40"
```

There is a file `test/test_blueprint.jl` with unit tests and that file starts with

```
using Test
include("../src/blueprint.jl") # Alternative 1
#using blueprint               # Alternative 2
using FunctionalCollections
using LinearAlgebra
...
```

The actual code being tested is in the file `src/blueprint.jl`.

#### Details about the problem

From the project root, I attempt to run the unit tests using the command `julia test/test_blueprint.jl`. When I run that command it produces the following output:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Setfield not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Setfield")` to install the Setfield package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:967
 [2] include(fname::String)
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:451
 [3] top-level scope
   @ ~/prog/julia/blueprint/test/test_blueprint.jl:8
in expression starting at /home/jonas/prog/julia/blueprint/src/blueprint.jl:1
in expression starting at /home/jonas/prog/julia/blueprint/test/test_blueprint.jl:8
```

suggesting that it cannot find the dependency `Setfield`. If I edit the top of the file `test/test_blueprint.jl` slightly from

```
include("../src/blueprint.jl") # Alternative 1
#using blueprint               # Alternative 2
```

to

```
#include("../src/blueprint.jl") # Alternative 1
using blueprint                 # Alternative 2
```

it still fails, but with a different error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package blueprint not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("blueprint")` to install the blueprint package.

Stacktrace:
 [1] require(into::Module, mod::Symbol)
   @ Base ./loading.jl:967
in expression starting at /home/jonas/prog/julia/blueprint/test/test_blueprint.jl:9
```

**Question:** How can I make the unit tests run from the command line?

Note that I *can* run the unit tests from within the Julia REPL in Emacs by activating the project using `C-c C-a` at the `src/blueprint.jl` file and calling `C-c C-b` at the unit test file `test/test_blueprint.jl`. My Julia version is 1.7.0 (2021-11-30). Don't hesitate to ask for more clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a few naming conventions that are probably not (but may be) contributing to the issues here:

- By convention, package names begin with a single capital, so I would recommend changing the name to `Blueprint` everywhere
- By default, `] test` runs tests found in the `test/runtests.jl`, so I would recommend naming your top-level testing script `runtests.jl` to avoid confusion, even though it does seem from the errors here that `test` is finding your `test_blueprint.jl` file one way or another.

Now, while I can't test this without the full code of your package, what I suspect is happening here is the following:

- Normally, dependencies of the package you are testing (let's say `MyPackage`) are not required in `test/Project.toml` because they are implicit in `MyPackage`. So after a successful `using MyPackage`, while they will still not be available to any functions written *in your test scripts* (`test/runtests.jl`), *will* be available to the functions written in `MyPackage` -- just as if you had typed `]using MyPackage` at the REPL and then run your test code there. This is the only reason you don't normally need to duplicate all the deps from the main `Project.toml` in `test/Project.toml`.
- Since the `using Blueprint` approach is failing here for other reasons, when you simply `include` the code from `src/blueprint.jl`, the `using`s within that file will in turn fail because those packages are not present in the active environment at `test/Project.toml` (even if they are present on your system elsewhere).
- Consequently, one quick fix to your problem with the current `include("../src/blueprint.jl")` approach would be to simply add those dependencies to your `test/Project.toml`

However, it would be more satisfying to fix the problem you are having with `using Blueprint`. I don't have enough information to debug this without seeing the full structure of your packages, but I would suggest as a start

- making sure that your code is [properly structured as a package](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/)
- testing that, even if unregistered, you can `] add` your package from the REPL by git repo URL (i.e. `] add https://some_website.com/you/Blueprint.jl`)

EDIT:
Upon inspection of the code linked in the comments (https://github.com/jonasseglare/Blueprint), a few other issues:

- Although they are already installed by default, standard libraries these days do need to be included in [deps]. In this case, that means the `LinearAlgebra` stdlib
- Any packages you are explicitly `using` in your test scripts, other than your package itself, *do* need to be added to `test/Project.toml`. I.e., any packages that you are *directly `using` functions from* in your test scripts (rather than just indirectly using via the exported functions of your package) do need to be included in `test/Project.toml`.
  In your case, the latter would appear to mean `LinearAlgebra` and `FunctionalCollections`, but not `Setfield` (that one only needs to be included in the regular `Project.toml`, since it's not being directly used in `runtests.jl`).

Consequently, with a few [minor changes to your repo](https://github.com/brenhinkeller/Blueprint) we are able to simply

```
] add https://github.com/brenhinkeller/Blueprint
] test Blueprint
```

or, since you preferred at the command line

```
user$ julia -e "using Pkg; Pkg.add(url=\"https://github.com/brenhinkeller/Blueprint\")
user$ julia -e "using Pkg; Pkg.test(\"Blueprint\")"
     Testing Blueprint
      Status `/private/var/folders/qk/2qyrdb854mvd2tn4crc802lw0000gn/T/jl_fSypP7/Project.toml`
  [c1615a0c] Blueprint v0.1.0 `https://github.com/brenhinkeller/Blueprint#master`
  [de31a74c] FunctionalCollections v0.5.0
  [37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra `@stdlib/LinearAlgebra`
  [8dfed614] Test `@stdlib/Test`
      Status `/private/var/folders/qk/2qyrdb854mvd2tn4crc802lw0000gn/T/jl_fSypP7/Manifest.toml`
  [c1615a0c] Blueprint v0.1.0 `https://github.com/brenhinkeller/Blueprint#master`
  [187b0558] ConstructionBase v1.3.0
  [de31a74c] FunctionalCollections v0.5.0
  [1914dd2f] MacroTools v0.5.9
  [ae029012] Requires v1.3.0
  [efcf1570] Setfield v0.8.1
  [56f22d72] Artifacts `@stdlib/Artifacts`
  [2a0f44e3] Base64 `@stdlib/Base64`
  [9fa8497b] Future `@stdlib/Future`
  [b77e0a4c] InteractiveUtils `@stdlib/InteractiveUtils`
  [8f399da3] Libdl `@stdlib/Libdl`
  [37e2e46d] LinearAlgebra `@stdlib/LinearAlgebra`
  [56ddb016] Logging `@stdlib/Logging`
  [d6f4376e] Markdown `@stdlib/Markdown`
  [9a3f8284] Random `@stdlib/Random`
  [ea8e919c] SHA `@stdlib/SHA`
  [9e88b42a] Serialization `@stdlib/Serialization`
  [8dfed614] Test `@stdlib/Test`
  [cf7118a7] UUIDs `@stdlib/UUIDs`
  [e66e0078] CompilerSupportLibraries_jll `@stdlib/CompilerSupportLibraries_jll`
  [4536629a] OpenBLAS_jll `@stdlib/OpenBLAS_jll`
  [8e850b90] libblastrampoline_jll `@stdlib/libblastrampoline_jll`
     Testing Running tests...
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
Plane tests   |    7      7
Test Summary:      | Pass  Total
Plane intersection |    2      2
Test Summary:        | Pass  Total
Plane intersection 2 |    4      4
Test Summary:   | Pass  Total
Plane shadowing |    3      3
Test Summary:    | Pass  Total
Polyhedron tests |    3      3
Test Summary:      | Pass  Total
Polyhedron tests 2 |    5      5
Test Summary: | Pass  Total
Beam tests    |    2      2
Test Summary:   | Pass  Total
Half-space test |    2      2
Test Summary:     | Pass  Total
Ordered pair test |    2      2
Test Summary:                | Pass  Total
Test plane/line intersection |    2      2
Test Summary:           | Pass  Total
Update line bounds test |   21     21
     Testing Blueprint tests passed
```

FWIW, you should also be able to mix and match those command-line and REPL approaches (i.e., install in repl, test via command line or vice versa).

While I had not originally considered this case, one additional possibility discussed in the comments is where one wishes to test the local state of a package without, or without relying upon, a git remote; in this case @Rulle reports that activating the package directory, i.e,

```
julia -e "using Pkg; Pkg.activate(\".\"); Pkg.test(\"Blueprint\")"
```

or

```
julia --project=. -e "using Pkg; Pkg.test(\"Blueprint\")"
```

or equivalently in the REPL

```
] activate .
] test Blueprint
```

will work assuming the package directory is currently the local directory `.`

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! My code is located here (https://github.com/jonasseglare/Blueprint). I tried the renamings that you suggested and the project structure seems OK AFAICT. After these changes, it did still not work. Then I discovered that if I specify the root path of my project using the `--project` option to `julia` (see my Answer), then I can getting it to work. But now I am having issues consistently reproducing the previous situation where I could not run the unit tests. It seems like there is some hidden state between calls to `julia` that I don't understand...

Comment: Ah, ok I see. The project structure is fine, but there were a few other issues, I will edit with an update

Comment: The other issue, which I didn't catch at first, was that you were running the tests manually, rather than via Pkg's built-in `test` command; that's why it didn't at first matter that you had a nontraditional name for your test script. Making the setup compatible with `Pkg.test` though has a lot of upsides in terms of convenience, compatibility with the existing CI scripts if you want to use e.g. github actions for testing, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the research! The changes you made look good. So what you propose in order to test the code from the command line is to run the two lines starting with `julia -e ...`. But the first one of these lines (the line `julia -e "using Pkg; Pkg.add(url=\"https://github.com/brenhinkeller/Blueprint\")`) seems to assume that I pushed my code to a repository somewhere. Is there a way to directly test the current local state of the code, independently of whether it is tracked by Git or not? That is what the command `julia --project=... test/runtests.jl` does, but maybe there is a cleaner way.

Comment: I experimented with modifications of the commands you wrote and came up with two commands that work (from the project root) and that answer my own question: (1) `julia -e "using Pkg; Pkg.activate(\".\"); Pkg.test(\"Blueprint\")"` and (2) `julia --project=. -e "using Pkg; Pkg.test(\"Blueprint\")"`. Unless you have a better idea, feel free to update your answer with these suggestions and I can approve it.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered the local case, good point

Answer (score 1):

*Possible answer to my own question:*

To make it work, specify the main project root directory on the command line when calling the script using `--project`. In this case, we would call

```
julia --project=/home/jonas/prog/julia/blueprint test/test_blueprint.jl
```

However, there seems to be some hidden state that I don't understand, because after this command has been run once, it seems as if the `--project` option can be omitted. On the other hand, I have also tried to provide a nonsense project directory, e.g. `/tmp`:

```
julia --project=/tmp test/test_blueprint.jl
```

and sometimes it will still run the unit tests (!) and sometimes it won't. But when it fails to run the unit tests, it will succeed again as soon as I specify the correct path, that is `/home/jonas/prog/julia/blueprint`. I don't understand also how this interacts with whether I use `using blueprint` or `include('../src/blueprint.jl')` but it seems as if, when I use `using`, it works only **iff** the `--project` path is set correctly. But I am still not sure.